# Trigger custom events on form submit google analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have to trigger a custom event on a specific form submit on my page. So I was thinking to bind `"onClick()"` event which looks some thing like below

```
<input id="test" class="testForm" type="submit" value="Submit" name="tester" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', 'Baby\'s First Birthday']);">
```

is it the recommended way of handling ?

1) If so, on submitting form will a new category and action created in my analytics  account automatically or I have to create the one's I am using in the `click()` event before hand using analytics UI

2) If not, provide me a work around how I can trigger custom events on form submit

Answer (score 0):

You can in a better way. Assuming your form is like:

```
<form id="theForm">
...
</form>
```

This js does the trick:

```
document.getElementById("theForm").addEventListener("submit", function(){
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', 'Baby\'s First Birthday']);
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Do I have to create the category and actions before hand or they will be created once the function call is made on form submit. I am refering point.. 1